# Networkx edge induced subgraph isomorphism

Tags: networkx, graph-theory, isomorphism

Consider the following snippet:

```py
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms import isomorphism
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

subg = nx.Graph()
subg.add_nodes_from([0]+[i+1 for i in range(6)])
subg.add_edges_from([(0, i) for i in range(1,7)])

bigg = nx.Graph()
bigg.add_nodes_from([0]+[i+1 for i in range(6)])
bigg.add_edges_from([(0, i) for i in range(1,7)]+[(i,i+1) for i in range(1,6)]+[(1,6)])

nx.draw(subg, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
nx.draw(bigg, with_labels=True)
plt.show()

matcher = isomorphism.GraphMatcher(bigg, subg)
print([x for x in matcher.subgraph_isomorphisms_iter()])
```

This returns no subgraph isomorphisms due to the fact that there exists no edge (1,6) in `subg` for example. How does one get networkx to not care about this? I would like to get the mapping of nodes from `subg` to `bigg` which respect all the relations defined in `subg` without respect to whether or not additional relations exist between the nodes in `bigg`.

Comment: Note that `.add_nodes_from([0]+[i+1 for i in range(6)])` is equivalent to `.add_nodes_from(range(7))`

Comment: [The documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/isomorphism.vf2.html#subgraph-isomorphism) specifically states that they're checking for nodes-induced subgraphs only:

*"Edge-induced subgraph isomorphisms are not directly supported, but one should be able to perform the check by making use of nx.line_graph()"*. I would suggest using `m = isomorphism.GraphMatcher(nx.line_graph(bigg), nx.line_graph(subg)); print(next(m.subgraph_isomorphisms_iter()))`; but actually, this matching of the edges doesn't translate to a matching of the vertices.

Comment: Also note that your manual creation of `subg` is equivalent to `subg = nx.star_graph(6)`; and your manual creation of `bigg` is equivalent to `bigg = nx.wheel_graph(7)`.

Comment: Hello @KenGoss; did you find a workaround?

Comment: @Stef yes, mostly. You've got to restructure both via netowrkx.line_graph() as you said, which works, but the thing nagging me now is that the referenced function does not maintain node or edge attributes.

Comment: @Stef The only way I see to get that is to copy the line_graph function source code, and augment it with copying the node attributes for each edge and the edge attributes for each node. Do you have a better idea? I'd really like a better idea.

Comment: Perhaps you could ask on https://cs.stackexchange.com the theoretical version of this problem: Is there a reduction from the edge-induced subgraph isomorphism problem to the vertex-induced subgraph isomorphism problem?